# Server Error in '/' Application Access is denied

Tags: asp.net, iis, model-view-controller

> This is a continuation of a question [I asker earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889336/iis-hosted-web-site-differs-from-local-web-site/54889949#54889949), but that after I solved I got immediately stuck again

My Asp.net Mvc application is not loading I run it browse to it in IIS, instead I get the following

[image]

### Stack Trace

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
>
> [ExternalException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command
>   being executed was
>   "C:\Users\JoeCampbell\source\repos\webapi\bin\roslyn\csc.exe" /shared
>   /keepalive:"10" /noconfig  /fullpaths
>   @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\f66da336\3058efba\3w2ezdih.cmdline".]
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCaptureUnimpersonated(SafeUserTokenHandle
>   userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection
>   tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)
>   +1767    System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(SafeUserTokenHandle
>   userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection
>   tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)
>   +208    System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(IntPtr userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection
>   tempFiles, String& outputName, String& errorName) +125
>   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.Compile(CompilerParameters
>   options, String compilerFullPath, String arguments, String&
>   outputFile, Int32& nativeReturnValue) +413
>   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] fileNames) +857
>   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] fileNames) +185
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() +1869
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +306
>   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean
>   isPrecompiledApp) +330
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +49
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +327
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command
>   being executed was
>   "C:\Users\JoeCampbell\source\repos\webapi\bin\roslyn\csc.exe" /shared
>   /keepalive:"10" /noconfig  /fullpaths
>   @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\f66da336\3058efba\3w2ezdih.cmdline".]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +73    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +603
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +36
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +831
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command
>   being executed was
>   "C:\Users\JoeCampbell\source\repos\webapi\bin\roslyn\csc.exe" /shared
>   /keepalive:"10" /noconfig  /fullpaths
>   @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\f66da336\3058efba\3w2ezdih.cmdline".]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +107    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +688

### Things I have tried

- Enabled Windows Authentication in Windows Features
- Changed the Windows Authentication property to Enabled in the Properties Window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by going to the folder listed in the stack trace and giving full permissions to webapi.localhost.net, however for you this is going to be your application pool identity.

For me it was in

> "C:\Users\JoeCampbell\source\repos\webapi\bin\roslyn\csc.exe"

I then right clicked the folder > Properties > Security >

Click your application pool identity within "Group or user names:"

Click edit, and then grant Full control

Click OK

[image]

Comment: "website name"? That's called application pool identity, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities